# Group Theory: Suggest video lecture (In English)

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, online-resources

Please suggest video lecture for following topics in Group Theory.

1. Revision of definition and examples of groups, subgroups.
2. Cyclic Groups, Classification of subgroups of cyclic groups.
3. Permutation Groups - Revision
4. Isomorphism, Cayley’s theorem, properties of isomorphisms, automorphism,
5. Revision of Cosets and Lagrange’s theorem. Orbit-stabilizer theorem, the rotation
   group of a cube and a soccer ball
6. External Direct Products
7. Normal subgroups and factor groups, Internal direct products
8. Group Homomorphism
9. Fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups
10. Sylow theorems
11. Finite simple groups

Comment: "" Suggest video lecture""?? When did I fall into the twilight zone? :<(

Comment: ah...this is probably the easiest part in abstract algebra. You could easily find a good book, read three times and become very comfortable with it. Jacobson did it within 100 pages. You may want Foote&Dummit for more exercises (200 pages).

Comment: Perhaps some of the videos and playlist on [MathDoctorBob}(https://www.youtube.com/user/MathDoctorBob) youtube channel cover some parts of the topics you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

[Ben Garside](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCu5cg_Jd9XSJL_CHUskgkGw)  has a collection of lectures on Group Theory.

You may find them [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4plQ5ppg9c&list=PLAvgI3H-gclb_Xy7eTIXkkKt3KlV6gk9_)
They seem to cover most of the topics you need.